# one-to-many relationship Controller HttpPost Create

Tags: c#, webapi

I have a problem with creating controller to my one to many relationship in webapi.
When creating user user is not adding to user list in role and role is not adding to role object in user.
I tried to save to database after role update but that didn't work either

> Role

```
  [Table("role")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Key]   
        public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    
        public string? RoleName { get; set; }
    
        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    
        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public Role() => Users = new HashSet<User>();
    } }
```

> User

```
   [Table("user")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UserId{ get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required"), MaxLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Name can't be longer than 60 characters")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required"), MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Password can't be longer than 50 characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set;}

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey(nameof(Role))]
        public Guid Role_Id { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public User() => Role = new Role();
    }
```

> Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Create(User user)
    {
       
        var Role = _repoWrapper.Role.FindByCondition(x => x.RoleName.Equals("Admin")).FirstOrDefault();
        user.Role = Role;
        user.Role.Users.Add(user);
        _repoWrapper.Role.Update(user.Role);
        _repoWrapper.User.Create(user);
        _repoWrapper.Save();
    }
```

Comment: You mean the rows are not being inserted in the database tables?

Comment: I'm guessing this is an Entity Framework based question?

Comment: @Chetan yes specific (user list is not updated to database and role object is not updated)